# How to use ExpandAll and CollapseAll For Grouping Grid using grouping feature

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, grouping

I am trying to use expandAll() and collapseAll() for a grouping grid Ext 4.1

But its not working after overriding:
getting errors expandAll() is not defined

```
            Ext.override(Ext.grid.feature.Grouping, {
                  collapseAll: function() {
                    var self = this, view = self.view;
                    view.el.query(self.eventSelector).forEach(function (group) {
                      var group_body = Ext.fly(group.nextSibling, '_grouping');
                      self.collapse(group_body);
                    });
                  },

                  expandAll: function() {
                    var self = this, view = self.view;
                    view.el.query(self.eventSelector).forEach(function (group) {
                      var group_body = Ext.fly(group.nextSibling, '_grouping');
                      self.expand(group_body);
                    });
                  }
                });
```

Here is my view file:

```
 Ext.define('MCT.view.MyGrid',
   {
     extend:'Ext.grid.Panel',
     initComponent:function(){
       var me  = this;
       this.bbar = [{xtype:'button',text:'Expand All', handler:function(){

          me.features[0].expandAll();

          this.callParent(arguments);


        }}];
     },
     features : [{
        ftype : 'grouping',
                    groupHeaderTpl :'.......',
                    startCollapsed : true
       }]

  });
```

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me in my app...

```
    xtype: 'tool',                   
    type: 'collapse-top',
    hidden: true,
    handler: function (event, target, owner, tool) {
        var agPanel = owner.up(), //getting thePanel
            view = agPanel.view,  
            gFeature = view.features[0]; //I júst have one feautre... so [0] works

        gFeature.collapseAll();
    }
```

In my case I have placed the collapse-top tool into the toolbar which triggers the groupes.
The curios thing is, that it only works if you get from the panel the view and from the view the grouping feature.

I think in your case it should work when you do this

```
var view = me.view;
view.features[0].expandAll();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... it works fine for Chrome. But in IE its throwing the error: Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'

Comment: Here is the fix for IE < 9

Comment: add this inside your script file :
      if ( !Array.prototype.forEach ) {
   Array.prototype.forEach = function(fn, scope) {
     for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
       fn.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
     }
   }
 }

Comment: Old but I wanted to add that Ext.each does work on IE but beware, it's said to be rather slow so do not apply on large collections of data! For small ones it's just fine.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the following code worked.

```
view.normalView.features[0].collapseAll();
view.normalView.features[0].expandAll();
```

*p.s: I used to get view.features as **`null`***

Comment: In my case, I use ExtJS 4.2.5, the first solution didn´t work for me, but this works perfect.Thanks.

Comment: Per the docs, [collapseAll](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping.html#method-collapseAll) and [expandAll](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping.html#method-expandAll)... now if only they had a toggle button that could be injected in the header.

Answer (score 0):

IE < 9 is not supporting forEach

Here is the link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference%2FObjects%2FArray%2FforEach#Compatibility

So the fix is:

```
  if ( !Array.prototype.forEach ) {
    Array.prototype.forEach = function(fn, scope) {
     for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
         fn.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
     }
   }
 }
```

It will work for IE and Chrome. Not tested in FF.

Comment: You can simply use `Ext.Array.each`